# Replace words in var string by elements of array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, replace

My code automatically search the string for color names and adds random number suffixes and stores them as elements in an array.

What I want is to create a new string with the new modified elements of my array.

Problem comes when string has multiple occurrences of the same color name.

What I need is to replace these occurrences with the different elements of my exported array one by one.

(I don't want to split string in Array, replace the same elements with the other array in a brand new one and then join it to a string. I need to modify the original string)

Example:

String changes through user input so if i have:

```
 str = ' little red fox is blue and red cat is blue';
```

then my code finds all color names and produces a new array like that:

```
array = [ 'red2354' , 'blue7856' , 'red324', 'blue23467'] ;
```

(my code adds RANDOM suffixes at the end of every color element but the order of my array is the same as the string's occurrences)

Desired Output:

```
 str = ' little red2354 fox is blue7856 and red324 cat is blue23467 ';
```

I tried so far:

```
var str = ' little red fox is blue and red cat is blue ';  

//I have split string to Array:

ar1 = [ "little","red","fox","is","blue","and","red","cat","is","blue"];

//var dup = matchmine(ar1) find all color duplicates :

var dup = ["red","blue","red","blue"];

//I've sorted all duplicates to appear only once for option B:

var dup2 = ["red","blue"];

//var res = modify(str) takes all color names and adds random suffixes:  


var res= ["redA" , "blueA" , "redB", "blueB" ] ;

//I have also create a new array with all strings in case I needed to match lengths:

var final = [ "little","redA","fox","is","blueA","and","redB","cat","is","blueB"];




   var i = ar1.length-1;         

       for ( i ; i >= 0; i--) {

    var finalAr = str.replace(ar1[i],final[i]); 
    str = finalAr;}

    alert(finalAr);
```

Problem is that loop goes and 1st time replace one by one all elements. So far so good but in the following loops replace the first again.

loops result:

```
   str = 'little redAB fox is blueAB and red cat is blue '
```

Desired output:

```
 str = 'little redA fox is blueA and redB cat is blueB '
```

Comment: *"I need to modify the original string"*: that is impossible. Strings are immutable in JavaScript. You always create a new string when you want something to change.

Comment: You always want to add "A" to first occurrences, "B" to second occurrences, ...etc. Or what is the logic?

Comment: @trincot The logic is random, it takes duplicates and adds extra string at the end. i.e my code finds red has 4 duplicates and calculates and stores elements like red874. All I want is to map 1st red with 1st redrandom element, 1st blue with 1st bluerandom etc

Comment: So you have an array with random numbers? Or do you not care what the numbers are (for reference later on), as long as the result has unique words?

Comment: BTW, why is the word "is" not considered a duplicate word?

Comment: @trincot think of it like dice.   User inputs a string "I roll 1d3" and my code wants to export "I roll 1d3=(4)" . Problem is if I have same dice in a string i.e "1d3 1d5 1d3". The expected output will be "1d3=(2) 1d5=(5) 1d3=(1)" .. My code only calculate strings digit d digit and exports digit d digit = (digit) that's why "is" not considered duplicate but I have solved these problems calculating.

Comment: Is your array `array = [ 'redA' , 'blueA' , 'redB', 'blueA' ];` to be seen as an *input* when we answer the question? If yes, how can we know that they are made up of `red` + `A` and not `re` + `dA`? Can you please be clear *what* the input is to the particular question you are asking? A sub title `INPUT` would be nice to have in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of your logic remains hidden in your question, like on what grounds you determine which word should get a suffix, or how that suffix is determined.

So my answer cannot be complete. I will assume *all* words that are duplicate (including "is"). If you already know how to isolate the words that should be taken into consideration, you can just inject your word-selection-logic where I have looked for duplicates.

For the suffix determination, I provide a very simple function which produces a unique number at each call (sequentially). Again, if you have a more appropriate logic to produce those suffixes, you can inject your code there.

I suggest that you create a regular expression from the words that you have identified, and then call `replace` on the string with that regular expression and use the callback argument to add the dynamic suffix.

Code:

```js
function markDupes(str, getUniqueNum) {
    // 1. Get all words that are duplicate (replace with your own logic)
    let dupes = str.match(/\S+/g).reduce(({words, dupes}, word) => ({
        dupes: words.has(word) ? dupes.concat(word) : dupes,
        words: words.add(word)
    }), {words: new Set, dupes: []} ).dupes;
    // Turn those words into a regular expression. Escape special characters:
    dupes = dupes.map(word => word.replace(/[\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'))
                 .join("|");
    let regex = new RegExp(dupes, "g");
    // Make the replacement of duplicate words and call the callback function:
    return str.replace(regex, word => word + getUniqueNum());
}

// Example has two inputs:

// 1. A function that determines the suffix:
//   Every call should return a different value
var getUniqueNum = ((i = 1) => {
    // ... here we choose to just return an incremental number
    //  You may implement some other (random?) logic here
    return () => i++; 
})();

// 2. The input string
let str = 'little red fox is blue and red cat is blue ';

// The call:
console.log(markDupes(str, getUniqueNum));
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you. I customized it a bit with my code that exports random suffixes and I'll do some tests and come back at you. So far seems to work flawlessly. Thank you sir!

Comment: you solved my problem with your answer but my code is still sloppy. Please take a look and see if I clarify my question better now. One problem I have with your solution is that my string may contain unique dice names which I also want to replace with the corresponding %d%=(%). Check my new example to understand better what I mean. Thanks again!

Comment: Well now my answer looks disconnected from your question. I will leave it like it is, as I feel this is becoming a new question. I would suggest you ask a completely new question and focus only on the one problem you have (if any?). Remember: sample input, expected output, your code, and what it produces instead. Those are critical elements in a quality question.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I am new user and this is my first question here. Do you recommend to change the question back to match your solution and create a new one on how to find unique dice elements and replace them or leave it as it is and expect a new approach of the whole problem here?

Comment: If you feel up to it, then that would indeed be a good thing to do.

Comment: Done! Already edit this one and made a new one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57360931/replace-specific-elements-unique-or-duplicates-from-a-string-in-js) . Much obliged if you have any ideas in my new question!

Answer (score 0):

Make an object that works as a map for your replacers:

```
const replacers =   {
    red: 'redA', 
    blue: 'blueB' 
}
```

Then split your string into an array of words and map over it, replacing as you go:

```
const inputStr = 'this is my red string blue words' 
const stringArr = inputStr.split(' ') 
const result = stringArr.map(word=> replacers[word]?replacers[word]:word). join(' ')
```

Comment: Problem is I have many "red" and "blue" in string and I want to substitute them with different replacers ex. 1st red : redA , 2nd red : redB etc. 

Also I don't have specific replaces, My code searches the string and creates the new replacers for my duplicates every time. I can't create an object with constant replacers

Comment: If I join(' ') my final array it will solve my question immediately but that's not the way I want to solve it.

Comment: @romp, in your question you seem to suggest in the first example that you have *input* with `array = [ 'redA' , 'blueA' , 'redB', 'blueA' ]`. But here you say you don't have specific replaces. I think you need to resolve that ambiguity by editing your question, and clearly define what exactly is the input and what is not.

Comment: @trimcot Sorry, I mean my code export a new Array with modified duplicates every time depending the string .And exports to an array new modified elements the same order my duplicates appear in string. String changes so every time I have different duplicates and my code export a new array every time string changes.

Comment: No problem, but can you please *edit* your question to  clearly define what exactly is the input and what is not?