# Replace specific elements (unique or duplicates) from a string in JS

Tags: javascript, replace, duplicates, unique

My code automatically search the string for /d+d/d+ elements (roll dices) and adds random number suffixes and stores them as elements in an array.

I want to create a new string with the new modified elements of my array.

(I don't want to split string in Array, replace the same elements with the other array in a brand new one and then join it to a string. I need to modify it and save it in a new string)

Example:

String changes through user input so if i have:

```
str = ' I roll 1d3 and 2d4+3 and 1d3 also 1d8 and 1d8 dice ';
```

then mydice(str) finds all dice names and produces a new array like that:

```
array = [ "1d3:[2]=2" , "2d4:[1,2]+3=6" , "1d3:[1]=1", "1d8:[7]=7", "1d8:[5]=5"] ;
```

Desired Output:

```
str = ' I roll 1d3:[2]=2 and 2d4:[1,2]+3=6 and 1d3:[1]=1 also 1d8:[7]=7 and 1d8:[5]=5 ';
```

Comment: _"I need to modify the original string"_: you can't. In JS strings are immutable. What ever process you use you'll have to return a new string.

Comment: AFAIK spliting and joining again is the only way

Comment: @Andy I edit the line to explain better. I mean I don't want a simple join(" ") to a new line. If I join "final' array my question is solved immediately but that's not what I want.

Comment: This is really... odd. To be blunt it seems very over-complicated, and I don't get the aversion to `join`. I partially want to say you can probably just use a string `replace` and/or maybe a tagged template, but I can't tell how you're getting `=(n)` and I don't understand what constitutes a duplicate. From your question it looks like you're showing point B to point D, and then asking how to change something arbitrary.

Comment: This question should better phrased in a way that does not need the story of *what already works*, but instead just presents the problem with clear input/output, focussing on the open problem *only*. So for instance, the mention of duplicates seems really unrelated to your actual question, since you *already* have an array with items you want to get replaced. This makes it confusing to readers. Just only focus on one thing, and skip the story that is "wrapped around" your problem.

Comment: Sorry, first time here and english not my native language. I'll follow these rules from now on.

Comment: @zfrisch I don't want join(" ") because str derives from a user textarea that is formatted.  If user uses breaks, newlines etc then the returned output string will not be formatted if I simply join(" ") the final array.

Comment: Could you explain what is happening with the `+3` in your string? It seems like a particular treatment. Are there other such manipulations that you foresee which are not in the example?

Comment: dice() takes 2d4+3 , make results for the 2 dice and adds 3 to total. ex. 2d4:[1,2]+3=6 means results were 1,2 and total sum is 1+2+3= 6 .   Only manipuIations are `ndn+n`  , `ndn*n` and `ndn+ndn` without +,* modifiers but with specific regex and your solution I'm covered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only the two items you provide as input (the string and the array with `ndn=(n)` kind of words), you can proceed as follows:

```js
let str = ' I roll 1d3 and 2d4+3 and 1d3 also 1d8 and 1d8 dice ';
let array = [ "1d3:[2]=2" , "2d4:[1,2]+3=6" , "1d3:[1]=1", "1d8:[7]=7", "1d8:[5]=5"];

let i = 0;
for (let item of array) {
    let find = item.replace(/:.*\]|=.*/g, "");
    i = str.indexOf(find, i);
    str = str.slice(0, i) + item + str.slice(i + find.length);
    i += item.length;
}

console.log(str);
```

It is assumed that the array is well-formed, i.e. that indeed those items were derived correctly from the string and all the string-parts before the equal sign (like "1d3") occur in the string.

Note that strings are immutable, so you cannot really mutate a string. The only way is to create a new string and assign it back to the same variable. But that is not mutation; that is assignment of a new string.

Comment: I edit my question and made it more specific with exact output

Comment: OK, I moved your modified input (array) in the snippet: now you seem to have two delimiters (`:` and `=`) and you seem to want to have things like  `+3` separated. Let me know if this is what you wanted, but such specific rules should better be explained in your question. Are the more rules like that?

Comment: Your solution works! I only add `rstr = item.toString()`  and changed `find=rstr.repl()` and `i+=rstr.length` for my code to work. Thanks again for your solutions!

Comment: Good to hear. If you have to do `toString()`, then that means your `array` is not an array of strings like you put in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your requirements, I think your solution is overcomplicated. I'd suggest something like this:

```js
const roll = dice => {
  const [num, max] = dice.split('d');
  let r = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    r += Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + 1;
  }
  return r;
}

let output = input = 'I roll 1d3 and 2d4 and 1d3 also 1d8 and 1d8 dice';
const matches = input.match(/\d+d\d+/g);
const rolls = matches.map(dice => `${dice}=(${roll(dice)})`);

rolls.forEach(roll => {
  const [dice] = roll.split('=');
  output = output.replace(new RegExp(` ${dice} `), ` ${roll} `);
});

console.log('IN:', input)
console.log('OUT:', output);
```

Comment: Thank Jordi but mydice() also made outputs if a user enters 2d4+5  or 1d2*9 etc and produce results "2d4+5: [2,3]+5=10" , 1d2*9: [1]+9=10

Comment: Oh, I didn't see these `+5`, `*9` and other allowed syntax in my first read.

Comment: It's NOT your fault! It's mine, I edit to make it more specific output!